# can linux be configured to blink an LED (GPIO) on disk activity?

Tags: linux, embedded, storage

I'm hoping to blink an LED that is wired up to a GPIO line whenever the USB connected disk has activity

is there an easy way to pull this off?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

Disk activity is recorded in real-time in "/proc/diskstats". All you need to do is loop every 100 ms, read this file and compare if any of the read or write counters for the USB block device changed. If they changed, blink the LED on the GPIO.

See the kernel source file "Documentation/iostats.txt" for information on the "/proc/diskstats" format.